# Mock HttpPostedFile in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, mstest

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateUserProfile(HttpPostedFile postedFile)
{ 
  //update operations
}
```

I have a method UpdateUserProfile where I am updating the image of a person using `HttpPostedFile`. It is working fine from Postman/Swagger. Now am writing UnitTestCases for the same. I have the below code

```
public void UpdateUserProfile_WithValidData()
{
   HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile;
   //httpPostedFile =??

  var returnObject =  UpdateUserProfile( httpPostedFile );

  //Assert code here
}
```

Now I have to give the image file to `HttpPostedFile` object from code manually which I am trying to do but couldn't. Please suggest me how to proceed further to mock image in the unit test.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Nope @Nkosi as my application specifically uses HttpPostedFile, so didn't changed it to HttpPostedFileBase

Answer (score 3):

`HttpPostedFile` is sealed and has an internal constructor. This makes it difficult to mock for your unit tests.

I would advise changing your code to use the abstract `HttpPostedFileBase`

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateUserProfile(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)  
  //update operations
}
```

Because it is an abstract class, that would allow you to create mocks directly via inheritance or via mocking frameworks.

For example *(using Moq)*

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateUserProfile_WithValidData() {
    //Arrange
    HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFile = Mock.Of<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    var mock = Mock.Get(httpPostedFile);
    mock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns("fakeFileName.extension");
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    //...populate fake stream
    //setup mock to return stream
    mock.Setup(_ => _.InputStream).Returns(memoryStream);

    //...setup other desired behavior

    //Act
    var returnObject = await UpdateUserProfile(httpPostedFile);

    //Assert
    //...Assert code here
}
```